# What underlying notion connects "roll" (in "volvere") to "leap" (in "*volvitare")?

Tags: etymology, vulgar-latin

> [[vault (v.1) :](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=vault&allowed_in_frame=0)]    [...] from Vulgar Latin **volvitare* "to turn, leap,"
>     frequentative of Latin *volvere* "to turn, turn around, roll" (see [volvox](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=volvox&allowed_in_frame=0)). [...]

I ask not about the meanings "turn" or "turn around" which both verbs share, but only about the meaning of "leap" that appears new to Vulgar Latin and (superficially) unconnected to the notion of to "turn, roll."

Comment: [wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vault#Etymology_2) suggests the "jump" sense of this word comes from **middle** French *volter*, which had a notion of “to turn or spin around; to frolic”; separately from the evolution of the noun sense of "vault" which comes from **old** French *volte* < vulgar Latin volvitare. So I'm not entirely sure that *volvitare has anything to do with jumping. But this is a comment and not an answer because I don't really know.

Comment: It should be remembered that the frequentative suffix *-(V?)t(a)-* often indicates not only frequency, but also intensity. But perhaps that has nothing to do with it, as Calchas suggests.

Comment: La Volta ( a dance in which the male assists his partner to leap in very much the same ways as a line-out forward ) was a favourite of Elizabeth I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [r/latin](https://old.reddit.com/r/latin/comments/gy7vha/what_semantic_notions_underlie_roll_in_volvere/) post assists.

[rocketman0739](https://old.reddit.com/user/rocketman0739). 1 month ago

> It mentions that *volutus* meant “bowed, arched.” Leaping does create an arched trajectory.

[CaiusMaximusRetardus](https://old.reddit.com/user/CaiusMaximusRetardus). 1 month ago

> I'm not sure I understand your question, but on what basis is *volvitare* founded ? The construction of the word doesn't make much sense and it doesn't seem to be attested. The -*itare* suffix usually denotes an intensive or iterative form, for *volvere*, it should be *volutare.*
>
> *Volutare* means "to turn a lot/often", so I can see why it could mean "to leap" in some specific cases. Think of smoke, for instance, when you blow through it (it turns on itself and goes in all directions), or a rock rolling down a rocky slope.